# Can't stop mysql on Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I reinstalled mysql on Ubuntu 12.10. Removing process works fine, but during the installation my attempt to set root password failed (because, as terminal said: the password had setted already). Then I tried to change password via safe_mode, but this action failed either, because I can't stop mysql.

When I try

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
```

I get

```
Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the service(8)
utility, e.g. service mysql stop
```

When I try

```
sudo service mysql stop
```

I get

```
stop: Unknown instance:
```

When I try

```
sudo mysqladmin shutdown
```

I get

```
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' exists!
```

Tell me please, what to do in this dead end?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`/etc/init.d/service_name stop` will still stop the service, but throw the deprecation warning, since `service` also works to stop a process.

That said, you running `service mysql stop` after you already ran `/etc/init.d/mysql stop` didn't work simply because `mysql` was already stopped, hence the `Unknown instance` error.

Likewise, `mysqladmin` can't stop the server at `localhost`, simply because the server at `localhost` isn't running an instance of `mysql` anymore.

Comment: You might want to add your two cents at [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27382295/how-to-stop-services-on-travis-ci-running-by-default) ...

Answer (score 1):

If you are root on the system, you can kill the process directly.

Use the command `ps -a` to list all the running processes.  Then locate the process id of the mysql process and use the commmand `kill -9 <MYSQL_PID>` to kill it.